# PID Controller for Thrust Vector Controlling of High Power Rocket

Tags: rockets, amateur-rocketry, sounding-rocket, model-rocketry, sugar-rocket

We are trying to design a Thrust Vector Control system for a High Power Rocket using PID Controller. Can anyone guide us what approach should we use to create this Controller?

*Rocket Details*:
Mass: 950 grams
Motor Peak Thrust: 62.10 N
Motor Average Thrust: 22.68 N

(If you need more details, please mention in the comment box...)

Comment: The PID controller for TWC does not differ from a controller for any other application so do some research about PID controllers, how to determine the parameters and than program a simulation to test your parameters.

Comment: What kind of bandwidth or response time do you think you will need? 10 Hz? 100? 1 kHz? Faster? I would suggest that your first step is to run a simple simulation by modeling your rocket numerically. Allow for variations in mass, center of mass, and moment of inertia as the propellant is used up, and add some lift. You have to either build a numerical model, or build hundreds of real models to tune your PID system so obviously the numerical model is the best way to go.

Comment: BPS.space (YouTube channel) has lots of public info about his thrust vectoring testing and setup

Comment: I am also working on such a PID controller. Maybe we can work together? Jonah